# Renaming VLAN Interfaces in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, rename, vlan

I need to know how to rename VLAN interfaces.  I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.04.  I'm running a networking application that takes frames on one interface applies things like delays and errors and then forwards the frames out another interface.  The default naming convention which names things `<interface>.<vlan>  e.g. eth0.2` will not work for my purposes because the program which parses the configuration script for the networking application doesn't like the decimal in the interface name.  I ran `vconfig set_name_type VLAN_PLUS_VID` which solves the decimal in the interface name problem, however, I can then no longer assign the same vlan id to multiple interfaces because they have the same name.

I know how to change physical interface names using udev rules, but because the vlan's will have the same MAC address and they aren't physical interfaces I can't use those rules to rename the interfaces.

Is there a way to rename any interface in linux, including the virtual ones?  Is there a way to specify your own naming convention for config set_name_type option without having to recompile the source of vconfig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  Simply run the following command

`ip link set <current name> name <new name>`

So if I had vlan eth0.3 and I wanted to call it eth0v3 I would run the command

`ip link set eth0.3 name eth0v3`